# Regex - extract characters after certain string

Tags: regex

what would be a Regex formula if I want to extract specific number of characters which appears after specified string.

For example: **Wed 09:00 18:00 09:00 01:00 00:00**, and I want to extract everything after word Wed.

Regards,

Comment: Provide some more details.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I would like to have this in.Net

Answer (score 0):

> **Caution**: JavaScript specific answer

You can use **positive lookbehind** - `?<=`

```
let str = 'Wed 09:00 18:00 09:00 01:00 00:00';
let word = 'Wed';
let count = str.length - 3;

let regex = new RegExp(`(?<=${ word }).{${ count }}`, 'gm');

console.log(str.match(regex)[0]);
```

But it seems that it doesn't have cross-browser support as indicated by [Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto) and [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) in the comments.

Instead, you can use [String.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

```js
let str = 'Wed 09:00 18:00 09:00 01:00 00:00';
let word = 'Wed';
let count = str.length - 3;

let newStr = str.split('').splice(str.indexOf(word) + word.length, count).join('');

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Did you try running your snippet?

Comment: @Nick i tried it and it outputs `" 09:00 18:00 09:00 01:00 00:00"`

Comment: I got `"SyntaxError: invalid regexp group"`. Javascript doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: @Toto I got the same result. Working now though